# How to properly shutdown my CentOS VM

Tags: vmware, shutdown, centos

Usually, I just do a sudo /sbin/shutdown now when in my VM and wait for it to logout into the bash shell. Then after that I just go to Power > Power Off. Is this the right way to shutdown my CentOS VM?

Comment: If you see the message on the screen saying something like `system has halted`, then yes.

Comment: Wait... you go to Power > Power Off in the shell?

Comment: No, after issuing the shutdown command via the shell, I wait for the system to halt, and then in the VM player GUI go to Power > Power Off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presuming VMware: if you have the vmware-tools installed in your VM, you should be able to issue the `shutdown -h now` command and it will power-off the VM for you.  This works for me with C4 and C5 VMs, on Server-1 and -2, Workstation 6.x, and ESX/ESXi.

Comment: If you are impatient, you can force a few disk flushes and hit the deck: sync;sync;sync;halt

Comment: `shutdown -h now` works on many virtualisation platforms, not just vmware.  Also in vmware you don't even need vmware-tools installed for the command (run on the guest) to power off the VM if the OS is recent and not too minimal like some router Linux distros.  Usually hypervisors emulate a motherboard with ACPI features so shutdown requires ACPI enabled in the guest.  I've noticed that if you do a minimal CentOS install, it does not enable this for you.

Comment: With CentOS you can ensure the ACPI daemon is installed with `yum install acpid` Then ensure the daemon starts at boot with `chkconfig acpid on` and start the service now with `service acpid start`

Answer (score 4):

You're close; the proper command is:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown **-h** now
```

1. Assuming that the `sudo` package is installed; otherwise, use `su` or similar.
2. Without the asterisks, of course.

This will shutdown then **halt** the computer.

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8   shutdown manual page... also look at the `-r` method to restart your computer. These are basic linux commands and really have nothing 'special' to do with a VM

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this works on CentOS 5.6 (Final) running as a VM on Win7 with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Without using VMWare Tools, On a VM CentOS machine the following command works fine.

```
shutdown
```

Comment: OP has stated that this is what he is already doing.